# When reading metadata using taglib

Tags: c++, tags, metadata, mp3, taglib

I use taglib library for read mp3 file's metadata.
There is no problem when the metadata of any file is in English.
but when the metadata is composed in Korean, Korean does not print correctly.
How do I solve this problem? Could you give me some tips?

```
TagLib::FileRef f(path);
TagLib::AudioProperties *audioProperties = f.audioProperties();
if (!f.isNull() && f.tag()) {
    TagLib::Tag* tag = f.tag();

    strcpy_s(musicFile->album, sizeof(musicFile->album),
        tag->album().toCString());
    strcpy_s(musicFile->artist, sizeof(musicFile->artist),
        tag->artist().toCString());
    strcpy_s(musicFile->title, sizeof(musicFile->title),
        tag->title().toCString());
    strcpy_s(musicFile->genre, sizeof(musicFile->genre),
        tag->genre().toCString());
```

Comment: The first and obvious question: You do have a Korean locale installed on your PC, right? And perhaps you could be a little more explicit than "not correctly"?

Comment: ㄴI sloved the problem. [wchar_t* -> char*] It works.